# QMake ignore/edit project file variable

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to reset LIBS variable of my project without touching pro file itself.

```
qmake fileName.pro LIBS=
```

this will not work, because "LIBS=" is performed before loading fileName.pro.

```
cat fileName.pro | grep -v "LIBS.*=" | qmake /dev/stdin
```

will not work too, qmake seems to NOT be intended for PIPE-ing.

so is there some other option for editing/ignoring/reseting variable insade qmake command line, without changing pro file.

Answer (score 0):

it was the **-after** option that i was looking for:

```
qmake fileName.pro -after LIBS=
```

works well.